# Ensuring string having \n in it ends with particular string

Tags: java, string

I get a string which I have to check if it ends with `SUCCESS`. The string I get is multi-line, that is, it has `\n` in it. If it ends with `SUCCESS.`, I have to return `true`, and if it ends with `FAILED.`, I have to return `false`. However

```
pValidationReport.endsWith("SUCCESS.")
```

evaluates to `false` even when the `pValidationReport` ends with `FAILED.` as can be seen below:

[image]

The method is as follows:

```
private boolean isValidationSuccess(String pValidationReport)
{
    if(pValidationReport.endsWith("SUCCESS."))
        return true;
    else if(pValidationReport.endsWith("FAILED."))
        return false;
}
```

What I am missing?

Comment: If the issue is that it has a new line (or other whitespace) at the end, use [`trim()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29). E.g. `if (str.trim().endsWith("SUCCESS."))`

Comment: Another issue is that your program probably didn't properly compile,  because you didn't tell it what to return when it ends with neither `SUCCESS` nor `FAILED`. It is marked with a red X. You should make sure that there is a return value for **all** possible strings even if you know that they will all end in one of two ways.

Comment: @khelwood yep maan it had `\n` after `SUCCESS.` :'¬\

Comment: @vikingsteve, i think it must **end** with "SUCCESS". `#contains()` will get it anywhere in the string.

Comment: @khelwood, make your comment as an answer, so it can be voted as the right one.

Comment: @GustavoCinque There's no need; someone else has put it as an answer.

Comment: @khelwood Sorry, didn't see that one.

Answer (score 2):

first trim the string then chcek for endsWith()

```
pValidationReport.trim().endsWith("SUCCESS.")
```

The Java String Trim method is an instance method that is use to remove extra spaces from the start and end of a string. The String Trim method is used on the string object or literal. In Java, Strings are immutable, so once they are created, the content cannot be modified. Due to this reason, the result will be a newly created string object with no spaces at both ends of a string.
it is evident that after trimming the string, it returns a new string object. When there is no space to trim at both sides, the same object of type String will be returned instead of a new one.

This endsWith() method returns a true if the character sequence represented by the argument is a suffix of the character sequence represented by this object, else false.

Answer (score 1):

If your input string has whitespace characters after the substring you're seeking for, it won't match. You could possibly use the regex for the purpose:

```
private boolean isValidationSuccess(String pValidationReport)
{
   Pattern successPattern = Pattern.compile(".*SUCCESS\\.\\s*$");
   return successPattern.matcher(pValidationReport).matches();
}
```

The \s* ensures that the **SUCCESS.** string at the end will be recognized even if followed by any arbitrary number of spaces, tabs, newlines, carriage-returns, form-feeds and vertical-tabs.
It is also possible to move the Pattern to a final instance variable and then just use the matcher in your method, saving the call to compile():

```
private final Pattern successPattern = Pattern.compile(".*SUCCESS\\.\\s*$");

private boolean isValidationSuccess(String pValidationReport)
{
       return this.successPattern.matcher(pValidationReport).matches();
}
```